# using ajax in flask to load live logs

Tags: javascript, python, html, flask

I am looking for some help, regarding my web server. I have a flask web server, designed to search in log files, and it does the job, but I need something else. To access the live data, to see the logs live.

It's an internal application, so the security is not a concern. The main thing it should do, is to open a file and basically simulate a "tail" command.Read the last lines, then just append the new ones, and basically that's all.
I was thinking to go with an AJAX call, but i'm not really good (at all) with JavaScript.

I was wondering about this solution :

```js
var byteRead=0;
setInterval(function(){

   $.ajax({ 
        type: "GET", 
        url: "GenNumber.txt",
        dataType: "text", 
        success: function (data) {  
            byteRead+= data.length;
            readdata(data);
        }, 
        headers: {
            "Range" : "bytes="+byteRead+"-"
        }
    });
},1000);
```

But im not quiet sure about it... neither how to adapt it (js side).

Does anyone have experience with this kind of issues or ideea how to start ?

Answer (score 0):

So, in short terms in case of anyone else needs something like this, the solutin is :

```
@login_required
def live():
    return render_template('live.html',user=current_user)
   
@views.route('/live_logs', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def live_logs():
    if request.method == 'GET':
        def generate():
            var_live = ''
            var = sp.Popen(['tail','-f',var_live],stdout=sp.PIPE,stderr=sp.PIPE)
            while True:
                var_live_log = var.stdout.readline()
                var_live_log = var_live_log.decode('utf-8')
                yield "data:" + str(var_live_log) + "\n\n"
                time.sleep(0.1)
        return Response(generate(), mimetype= 'text/event-stream')
```

And the HTML file should look like this :

```
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    </head>
<body>
    <br>
    <hr>
<section class="section">
<div class="livelog">
    <div class="columns is-centered is-mobile"> 
        <div class="column is-dark notification is-four-fifths">
            <div class="is-size-7 has-text-warning" id="display">
                <ul id="display_list" class="logs"></ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</section>
</body>
</html>
{% endblock %}
```

Obviously this may differ, based on base.html

But this code will create a tail session which and stream it to the browser, also can be modified to read a file or smth..